# Python code running for hours, no results or error

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I am running the following code. It has been running hours, without any result. It is uses a 1000 row dataframe called df. It first creates an empty matrix and then fills it with the difference between values (car) in the original dataframe. Any help would be appreciated.

```
d_iff = np.empty(shape=(1000,1000), dtype="float")
for i in range(1000):
  for j in range(1000):
    d_iff [i,j] = np.square(((df.car[i] - df.car[j])/0.5)) + np.square (((df.table[i] - df.table[j])/10))
```

Comment: couldn't you vectorize it? drop the inner loop and do `d_iff [i,:] = np.square(((df.car[i] - df.car[:])/0.5)) + np.square (((df.table[i] - df.table[:])/10))` (don't bash me if this is stupid)

Comment: small time opts: store the value of `df.car[i]` and `df.table[i]` in locals to avoid accessing them all the time. have you tested with 100,100 too? The idea if you want to optimize is to get something working with fewer values, and try to reduce the time with that setting. Then, increase.

Comment: I think accessing numpy array is slow. They aren't to be used as vectors for efficiency. Try converting to lists, and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Can you post a sample data set (5 rows), short description of what you are trying to achieve and expected/desired data set?

Comment: it eventually worked. my apologies, but in the code I was running, I included another step in the loop, which is what I think was slowing it all down.